# Using Excel formula within sql

Tags: sql, formula

I have the below data table:

[image]

and I would like to create a summary of this table to look something like the below:

[image]

I can do this in excel via a sumifs but not sure how to do this in sql for the same / similar result.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `group by` clause, for example:

```
select Department, sum(Basic_Time) from table group by Department
```